# Discord.JS - Return original owner ID via a reply message using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I've been scouring the internet and have yet to find a way of doing this.

Simply put;

1. Person 1 posts a message in a Discord channel i.e. "Thanks"
2. Person 2 replies to Person 1's message with a prefix command and a channel ID

I then want the bot to grab the following information;

1. Original messageID (Person 1's message)
2. Original message Content (The message itself)
3. Replier messageID (Person 2)
4. Replier message Content (which holds the commands)

I have read a few bits and pieces and found I apparently could do this with references and 'resolved' but below returns an undefined for reference.

```
  if (message.reference?.resolved) {
            var old_message = await message.channel.fetch_message(message.reference.messageId)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out **messageCreate** works, **message** is deprecated.

```
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return; 
    
    var reply = message.reference;
    var old_message = await message.channel.messages.fetch(reply.messageId)
```